# i want to apply bold format on word Vadodara i tried with following code but it's not working

Tags: c#, ms-word

```
namespace WordDocument
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  CreateDocument();

    }
    private void CreateDocument()
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application winword = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

        winword.Visible = true;

        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document = winword.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

        document.Content.SetRange(0, 0);
        document.Content.Text = "SALE DEED OF THE IMMOVABLE PROPERTY BEING FLAT NO. " + textBox1.Text + " ON THE " + textBox2.Text + " Floor IN THE SCHEME KNOWN AS '" + textBox3.Text + "' FOR Rs. " + textBox4.Text + "-00. (Rs. " + textBox5.Text + " Only)." + Environment.NewLine;
        document.Content.Font.Name = "Arial";
        document.Content.Bold = 1;
        document.Content.Font.Size = 13;
        document.Content.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphJustify;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph para4 = document.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
        para4.Range.Text = "     Resi at- " + textBox11.Text + " :Vadodara.";
        para4.Range.Font.Name = "Arial";
        para4.Range.Font.Size = 13;
        para4.Range.Font.Bold = 0;
        object objStart2 = para3.Range.Text.IndexOf("V");
        object objEnd2 = para3.Range.Start + para3.Range.Text.IndexOf(".");

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rngBold2 = document.Range(ref objStart2, ref objEnd2);
        rngBold2.Bold = 1;
        para4.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may Try this....

```
private void InsertMultiFormatParagraph(string psText, int piSize, int piSpaceAfter = 10)     
{
    Word.Paragraph para = mdocWord.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref mobjMissing);

    para.Range.Text = psText;
    // Explicitly set this to "not bold"
    para.Range.Font.Bold = 0;
    para.Range.Font.Size = piSize;
    para.Format.SpaceAfter = piSpaceAfter;

    object objStart = para.Range.Start;
    object objEnd = para.Range.Start + psText.IndexOf(":");

    Word.Range rngBold = mdocWord.Range(ref objStart, ref objEnd);
    rngBold.Bold = 1;

    para.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
}
```